# remove the outliers in bwplot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm creating a bwplot{lattice} and I would like it not to display the outliers. Here is example code:

```
m <- mtcars

m$gear <- factor(m$gear)
m$vs <- factor(m$vs)
m$am <- factor(m$am)

bwplot(drat ~ gear | am + vs,
   data = m)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set `do.out=FALSE`, like this:

```
bwplot(drat ~ gear | am + vs, data = m, do.out = FALSE)
```

Pro tip: as is often the case with **lattice** plotting functions, that argument is documented in `?panel.bwplot` (the function to which `bwplot()` passes it on) rather than in the already-way-too-long-to-be-readable `?bwplot`.

Comment: By any chance do you know how to reduce the scale of the y axis after I remove the outliers? I'm left with a lot of white space. I have been trying to find it, but frankly quite lost with lattice still. Thanks

Comment: I could figure that out, but frankly it'll probably be easier for you just to: (1) run `bwplot()` once as above; (2) take a look at the plot and decide what you'd like the y-limits to be; (3) specify those via, e.g., `ylim=c(2.5, 4.5)`.

Comment: If you did want to automate calculation of more appropriate limits, you'd need to roll your own 'prepanel' function, riffing off of what's in `prepanel.default.bwplot()`. It would need to calculate the boxplot stats in the same way that `panel.bwplot()` does (the most relevant bit being this: `tapply(y, factor(x, levels = levels.fos), stats, coef = coef, do.out = do.out)`, where `stats` is really the function `boxplot.stats`). It could then use components of the resulting list to calculate the `ylim` piece of the list returned by your custom prepanel function. As I said, not easy!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
bwplot(drat ~ gear | am + vs,data = m,
      par.settings=list(plot.symbol=list(pch=NA)))
```

The outlier symbols are controlled through plot.symbol, which you get to via par.settings.